# Passar um array de uma consulta para todas as páginas Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tem uma view que se repete em todas as outras através de um

```
$this->load->view('menu');
```

teria uma forma de carregar a consulta do menu dinâmico em todas as outras views com a linha acima?
Se eu fizer isso em todos os controllers, naturalmente da certo:

```
$dados['menus'] = $this->Menu_model->menus();
$this->load->view('layout/menu', $dados);
```

... mas eu gostaria de saber se tem uma forma de não repetir isso nos controllers e usar a linha acima em apenas um local, como se fosse uma constante.

Valeu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar uma classe controladora `MY_Controller` que extenda a classe `CI_Controller` do CodeIgniter e então fazer todos os seus controladores extender a sua classe customizada. A lógica é criar um arquivo base que tenha tudo o que vai se repetir em todas as páginas do seu site, ou seja, conteúdos estáticos (ex.: headers, menus e rodapés), esse arquivo base eu chamo de `v_base`. A partir de então, toda vez que você for chamar uma página nova, seria acionado o `v_base` e dentro desse arquivo, seria chamado o seu conteúdo.

Nessa classe customizada, você teria mais ou menos a seguinte configuração:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    private $dadosPagina; // Informações (variáveis) que serão usados na página carregada
    private $v_base; // Arquivo base da interface (menus fixos, cabeçalho e rodapé da página)

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->dadosPagina = array();
        $this->v_base = array();
    }

    /**
     * Adiciona dados à página que será carregada, como variáveis
     * @param String $nome Identificador da variável
     * @param String $valor Valor a ser usado a partir da chamada de seu identificador
     */
    protected function addDadosPagina($nome, $valor) {
        $this->dadosPagina[$nome] = $valor;
    }

    /**
     * Adiciona um título à página que será carregada
     * @param String $valor Título para a página
     */
    protected function addTituloPagina($valor) {
        $this->dadosPagina['tituloPagina'] = $valor;
    }

    /**
     * Carrega uma página do site
     * @param String $pagina Caminho do arquivo da página (path) (sem a extensão)
     */
    protected function mostrarPagina($pagina) {            
        $this->v_base['conteudo'] = $this->load->view($pagina, $this->dadosPagina, true);
        $this->load->view('v_base', $this->v_base);
        $this->dadosPagina = array(); // zerar atributo dadosPagina
        $this->v_base = array(); // zerar atributo v_base
    }

}
```

A chamada dessas funções, seriam dessa forma:

```
class Paginas_Usuarios extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Carregar página de cadastro de usuário.
     */
    public function cadastrar_usuario() {
        $this->addTituloPagina('Cadastro de Usuário');
        $this->mostrarPagina('usuario/v_cadastrar');
    }
}
```

Comment: entendi, mas no meu caso o conteúdo é dinâmico. O menu e submenu é montado a partir das páginas cadastradas no banco e são carregadas de acordo com as permissões do usuário. Mas me foi útil, em todo o resto(conteúdo estático) usei a logica que me passou.

Comment: Mas utilizar a lógica de menus "estáticos" não lhe restringe a mudar o conteúdo do menu de acordo com a permissão. A única coisa que é estática é a estrutura do HTML.

Comment: Se você passar no dadosPagina, as permissões do usuário logado, dá perfeitamente pra utilizar na view dos menus, essa variável e fazer a verificação :D